# Running Hbase as DB in windows with servlet jsp

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, hadoop, hbase

I am a windows user and want to learn Hbase with java servlet and jsp. Basically, i want to use native JavaAPI for Hbase and use as my Primary Database for storage. I can not able find any relevant solutions to set up these things in windows without a Virtual box.

Can any one just suggest me any link that i can start developing these with eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this: https://hbase.apache.org/cygwin.html? I used to configure HDFS/HBase in pseudo-distributed mode in this configuration.